# How to Sqlite database with password access from Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, sqlcipher

i made a password sqlite database file via sqlitestudio SQLSicpher, how can i access the data base from qt?, I tried

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(dbLocation);
db.setPassword("thPassworde");
```

but it cannot open the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt does not officially support SQLCipher but there are several projects that create a driver between them [QtCipherSqlitePlugin](https://github.com/devbean/QtCipherSqlitePlugin), to install it I use the following commands:

```
git clone git@github.com:devbean/QtCipherSqlitePlugin.git
qmake
make
sudo make install
```

**Note:** If you are on windows you must use [`jom`](http://wiki.qt.io/jom), `nmake` or [`mingw32-make`](https://mingw-w64.org/) depending on the configuration you have.

This library offers an [example project](https://github.com/devbean/QtCipherSqlitePlugin/tree/master/testapp) where the main.cpp is the following:

```
#include <QtSql>
#include <QCoreApplication>

#ifdef Q_OS_IOS
#  include <QtPlugin>

Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(SqliteCipherDriverPlugin)
#endif

#define CONNECTION_FAILED -1

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    Q_UNUSED(app);

    qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
    QString dir = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation);
//    QString DB_FILE_PATH = dir + "/test_chacha20.db";
    QString DB_FILE_PATH = dir + "/test_sqlcipher.db";
    qDebug() << "DB File Path is:" << DB_FILE_PATH;

    QSqlDatabase dbconn = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("SQLITECIPHER");
    dbconn.setDatabaseName(DB_FILE_PATH);
    dbconn.setPassword("test");
    dbconn.setConnectOptions("QSQLITE_USE_CIPHER=sqlcipher; QSQLITE_ENABLE_REGEXP");
    if (!dbconn.open()) {
        qDebug() << "Can not open connection: " << dbconn.lastError().driverText();
        exit(CONNECTION_FAILED);
    }

    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("create table mapping (id int, name varchar)");
    query.exec("insert into mapping values (1, 'AAA')");
    query.exec("insert into mapping values (2, 'BBB')");
    query.exec("insert into mapping values (3, 'CCC')");
    query.exec("insert into mapping values (4, 'DDD')");
    query.exec("insert into mapping values (5, 'EEE')");
    query.exec("insert into mapping values (6, 'FFF')");
    query.exec("insert into mapping values (7, 'GGG')");
    query.exec("select * from mapping where name regexp '(a|A)$'");
    if (query.next()) {
        qDebug() << "Regexp result: " << query.value(0).toInt() << ": " << query.value(1).toString();
    } else {
        qDebug() << "This plugin does not support regexp.";
    }
    qDebug() << "----------" << endl;
    query.exec("select id, name from mapping");
    while (query.next()) {
        qDebug() << query.value(0).toInt() << ": " << query.value(1).toString();
    }
    qDebug() << "----------" << endl;
    query.exec("update mapping set name='ZZZ' where id=1");
    query.exec("select id, name from mapping");
    while (query.next()) {
        qDebug() << query.value(0).toInt() << ": " << query.value(1).toString();
    }
    qDebug() << "----------" << endl;
    query.exec("delete from mapping where id=4");
    query.exec("select id, name from mapping");
    while (query.next()) {
        qDebug() << query.value(0).toInt() << ": " << query.value(1).toString();
    }
    query.exec("drop table mapping");
    dbconn.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how to install it, sorry if this noob question, i need to know because i see many project that need to compile and i'm kind lose, thanks

Comment: @ZoroAllam To compile the QtCipherSqlitePlugin project I have indicated that you must follow the 4 steps

Comment: @ZoroAllam whats is your OS?

Comment: microsof windows 7

Comment: @ZoroAllam okay, first download the project using the following link: https://github.com/devbean/QtCipherSqlitePlugin/archive/master.zip

Comment: i dawnload the project

Comment: @ZoroAllam now unzip it and open a CMD with administrator permission located in the project folder

Comment: @ZoroAllam Have you opened it as an administrator? Is it open in the same QtCipherSqlitePlugin project folder?

Comment: sorry i opened the cmd for windows and typed in cd then the path of the project

Comment: @ZoroAllam okay, the execute `qmake`, then execute `nmake`

Comment: it give 'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @ZoroAllam What is your compiler?

Comment: i use qt 5.6 msvc 2013

Comment: @ZoroAllam I do not remember the name of the command but you can get it easily, for it creates a project in Qt Creator and when you compile it appears some commands, then share those lines and I will tell you what the command is.

Comment: this is the compiler output 08:38:44: Running steps for project manyTable...
08:38:44: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
08:38:44: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
 C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
08:38:44: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
08:38:44: Elapsed time: 00:00.

Comment: @ZoroAllam try with `jom` or `C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe`

Comment: it give at the end Error 2, sorry if this take your time

Comment: @ZoroAllam I do not understand your comment, what is the error message?

Comment: c\release -IC:\Qt\QT
-EVE~1.0\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Fo.obj\release\ @C:\Users\zoro\AppDa
ta\Local\Temp\sqlite3secure.obj.2940.62.jom
jom: C:\Users\zoro\Downloads\QtCipherSqlitePlugin-master\sqlitecipher\Makefi
le.Release [.obj\release\regexp.obj] Error 1
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
jom: C:\Users\zoro\Downloads\QtCipherSqlitePlugin-master\sqlitecipher\Makefi
le.Release [.obj\release\sqlite3secure.obj] Error 1
jom: C:\Users\zoro\Downloads\QtCipherSqlitePlugin-master\sqlitecipher\Makefi
le [release-all] Error 2

Comment: @ZoroAllam okay, I think it will be easier if Qt Creator is used, for that it deletes the decompressed folder and returned folder unzips the file, then opens the QtCipherSqlitePlugin.pro with Qt Creator, sets it in release mode and compiles it.

Comment: @ZoroAllam or add `C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin` to Environment Variables and then execute `jom` again